# Generate a link from a service

Tags: url, symfony, service

How can I generate a link from a service?  I've injected "router" inside my service, however generated links are `/view/42` instead of `/app_dev.php/view/42`. How can I solve this?

My code is something like this:

**services.yml**

```
services:
    myservice:
        class: My\MyBundle\MyService
        arguments: [ @router ]
```

**MyService.php**

```
<?php

namespace My\MyBundle;

class MyService {

    public function __construct($router) {

        // of course, the die is an example
        die($router->generate('BackoffUserBundle.Profile.edit'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please paste the code where you generate the URLs?

Comment: If you access your site through `http://test/app_dev.php`, the links will be with app_dev.php. For `http://test` they will be without app_dev.php...

Comment: @meze : I access to the page threw app_dev.php, but links haven't got this part in the url. That's the problem.

Comment: Is the URL generated correctly if you try it in a template?

Comment: @kuba, yes. Someone told me to set a context with $urlgenerator->getContext()->setHost($host), is there a way to get context and/or host using dependency injection ?

Comment: @NisonMaël What about using an Apache rewrite rule like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]` (if you are using Apache of course)?

Comment: @noisebleed, well, I would like to resolve this issue instead of hide it ;D For example, what if I have multiple symfony installations, like /a/app.php and /b/app.php ?

Comment: @NisonMaël You would put a `.htaccess` file for every `web` folder. Not seeing a problem there. That's what I'm doing. But if you want to keep `app_dev.php` that's fine, let's drop this hypothesis.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

So : you will need two things.

First of all, you will have to have a dependency on @router (to get generate()).

Secondly, you must set the scope of your service to "request" (I've missed that).
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html

Your `services.yml` becomes:

```
services:
    myservice:
        class: My\MyBundle\MyService
        arguments: [ @router ]
        scope: request
```

Now you can use the @router service's generator function !

---

**Important note regarding Symfony 3.x**: As the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html) says,

> The "container scopes" concept explained in this article has been
>   deprecated in Symfony 2.8 and it will be removed in Symfony 3.0.
>
> Use the `request_stack` service (introduced in Symfony 2.4) instead of
>   the `request` service/scope and use the `shared` setting (introduced in
>   Symfony 2.8) instead of the `prototype` scope (read more about shared
>   services).

Comment: I don't get it. How did it help? Scope has nothing to do with `app_dev.php`.

Comment: If the request is not available when the router is used, the context (getContext()) of the router won't use the request informations (f.e. the host), and the path won't be fully generated. Setting the scope ensure that the request will be alive when my service will be created

Note that there was a second specific problem : I was loading my services at the bundle's boot, so the request wasn't loaded yet.

Comment: "you will have to have a dependency on @router (to get generate())." I don't understand, from what is your answer there different from your question?

Comment: @Toskan I was doing the first requirement (`@router` dependency) right, but I was missing the second requirement (using `scope: router`), so it wasn't working. Using both of them solves the issue.

Comment: I am getting this error when doing as you suggest:
`ScopeCrossingInjectionException: Scope Crossing Injection detected: The definition "myservice" references the service "router.default" which belongs to another scope hierarchy. This service might not be available consistently. Generally, it is safer to either move the definition "myservice" to scope "container", or declare "router" as a child scope of "container". If you can be sure that the other scope is always active, you can set the reference to strict=false to get rid of this error.`

Comment: if I set it to container, it works, with whatever sideeffects this could produce

Comment: Well, it was required more than two years ago. It's very possible that the current Symfony release has a different way to manage this - I'm no longer working with Symfony!

Comment: @Toskan: In your service please add:

    `use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;`

In service constructor add

    `RouterInterface $variableName,`

And at the end remove `scope=router` from `service.yml`.

Comment: Sidenote: if you want to use `myservice` as a dependency in other services, propably you will have to pass it with `=` at the end (like `arguments: [ @myservice= ]`), it's yml syntax to set `strict=false`. Otherwise `ScopeWideningInjectionException` could be thrown. However, the `=`-syntax does not work when defining services as Twig's globals.

Answer (score 22):

For **Symfony 4.x**, it's much easier follow the instructions in this link [Generating URLs in Services](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#generating-urls-in-services)

You only need to inject `UrlGeneratorInterface` in your service, and then call `generate('route_name')` in order to retrieve the link.

```php
// src/Service/SomeService.php
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

class SomeService
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }
    public function someMethod()
    {
        // ...

        // generate a URL with no route arguments
        $signUpPage = $this->router->generate('sign_up');
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43630670/how-to-generate-absolute-url-from-early-auto-loaded-symfony-3-router/43634938#43634938), but using Symfony 3.
While eluded to in the previous answer, it was a bit tricky to find out how exactly one would use `request_stack` to achieve the same thing as `scope: request`.

In this question's case, it would look something like this:

The services.yml config

```
services:
    myservice:
        class: My\MyBundle\MyService
        arguments:
            - '@request_stack'
            - '@router'
```

And the MyService Class

```
<?php

    namespace My\MyBundle;

    use Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext;

    class MyService {

        private $requestStack;
        private $router;

        public function __construct($requestStack, $router) {
            $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
            $this->router = $router;
        }

        public doThing() {
            $context = new RequestContext();
            $context->fromRequest($this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest());
            $this->router->setContext($context);
            // of course, the die is an example
            die($this->router->generate('BackoffUserBundle.Profile.edit'));
        }
    }
```

**Note:** Accessing RequestStack in the constructor is [advised against](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/17273#issuecomment-297650396) since it could potentially try to access it before the request is handled by the kernel. So it may return null when trying to fetch the request object from RequestStack.