# generateUrl outside controller

Tags: symfony

Is there a possibility to use generateUrl() method outside of controllers?

I tried to use it in a custom repository class with `$this->get('router')`, but it didn't work.

**update**

I've found a temporary solution here:

http://www.phamviet.net/2012/12/09/symfony-2-inject-service-as-dependency-in-to-repository/

I injected the whole service container into my repository, although it's "not recommended".

But it works for now.

**update2**

Injecting router instead of the whole container is probably a better idea :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057309/generate-a-link-from-a-service

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't inject the container into your repository... Really, don't !

If I were you, I would create a service and injects the router in it. In this service, I would create a method, that uses the repository and adds the needed code using the router.

That's way less dirty and easy to use/understand for another developer.

Comment: injecting just router is also a bad idea?

Comment: It's a better idea but unfortunately still not a good idea. :<
Repositories purpose is to write some custom queries, no doing stuff like redirection. It's actually more a matter of good practices.

Comment: Gmajoulet, perhaps some links to the documentation would help

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/service_container.html

Like I said : try to create a service, and inject the router component in it (and the entitymanager to get your repository). Then you'll be able to work with the router and with your repository logic, in a clean way.

Comment: the way that you cannot define what kind of interface is returned makes it actually not really easier to understand for a developer

Comment: I think that this answer should be chosen as the right one.

Answer (score 18):

If you take a look in [the source code of `Controller::generateUrl()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php#L47-50), you see how it's done:

```
$this->container->get('router')->generate($route, $parameters, $referenceType);
```

Basically you just enter the name of the route (`$route` here); if exists, some parameters (`$parameters`) and the type of reference (one of the constants of the [`UrlGeneratorInterface`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Generator/UrlGeneratorInterface.php#L36-56))

Comment: But $this->container is also not available in repositories. How do i pass container to them?

Comment: You completely missed the point of the question in this answer!!  Use of ""this" assumes that you're inside the controller.

Comment: @cartbeforehorse no, this asumes assumes your in an object which can be instantiated...

Comment: @WouterJ I think you missed the point of my comment. The whole point of the question is that `$this->container` and `$this->generateUrl()` cannot be used, because the class we're coding in is not an extension of the `Controller` (or `ContainerAware`) object. Unless I missed something.

Answer (score 2):

Inject the router itself into your EntityRepsitory (like described on Development Life blog's post [Symfony 2: Injecting service as dependency into doctrine repository](http://www.phamviet.net/2012/12/09/symfony-2-inject-service-as-dependency-in-to-repository/)), then you can use `$this->router->generate('acme_route');`

Comment: Your link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

in symfony 4 and Sylius when the FormType extends an (ex.) AbstractResourceType

```
class PostType extends AbstractResourceType
{

    private $router;
    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router, $dataClass, $validationGroups = [])
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        parent::__construct($dataClass, $validationGroups);

    }
}
```

Services.yaml :

```
app.post.form.type:
        class: App\Form\Admin\Post\PostType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
        arguments: ['@router.default', '%app.model.post.class%' ]
```